# Are divs and spans allowed inside form elements?

Tags: forms, html

I am asking this question to test the validity of my HTML. I can very well try this out (and I have, and it's possible), but I'm simply curious whether or not this is allowed in HTML. If not, how can one simulate a div or span element inside a form? Using blockquote?

Comment: @CharithJ: I downvoted for the "This question does not show research effort" clause, and the "This question is not useful" clause. Where on Earth did these ideas come from? There's not a trace of explanation, it just seems random. I didn't give a reason because they have already been given.

Comment: @David: If I understand you correctly you wanted to know whether this is officially endorsed by XHTML, because the W3C form spec just talks about form controls explicitly as content of a form. In their examples the only non-control they use is a `p` element. I think in this light your question seems very valid and absolutely not downvote-worthy. Maybe you could be more explicit in your question?

Comment: @emboss: I didn't downvote, but I think your interpretation of his question is perhaps the most generous one possible, given absolutely zero supporting context in the question itself.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`form` is a *block-level* element in HTML.  Typically, block-level elements allow both *block-level* and *inline* children.  Both `div` and `span` are valid children of `form`.

There are a ton of resources online to learn more about this topic, for example:

http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#h-7.5.3

It may also benefit you to read about the box model, as this is one of the most fundamental concepts of web design/development.

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can. And it is also "officially allowed" by the XHTML standard, if you look into the [XHTML XSD](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1-schema/#schemas), you will find

```
<xs:complexType name="form.content">
  <xs:annotation>
    <xs:documentation>
      form uses "Block" excluding form
    </xs:documentation>
  </xs:annotation>
  <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
    <xs:group ref="block"/>
    <xs:group ref="misc"/>
  </xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>
```

"block" encompasses `div` and "misc" contains `span`. The "documentation" part points out one particular thing you are *not* allowed to do: nest a `form` within another one.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's valid and you can use any number of divs, spans or blockquotes inside a form. You can always use [W3C Markup Validation Service](http://validator.w3.org/) to check your html.

Eg:

```
<body>
    <form id="Form1">
    <div id="wrap">
         <div id="content-wrap" class="content-wrap-admin">
         </div>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

I must correct **emboss**' answer.

In the **XHTML 1.0 Strict DTD** that he quotes, the group `misc` does not refer to inline elements. Instead, it refers to the following 4 elements: `noscript`, `ins`, `del` and `script`.

```
<!ENTITY % misc.inline "ins | del | script">
<!ENTITY % misc "noscript | %misc.inline;">
```

So to answer the question, XHTML 1.0 Strict does not allow `span` elements inside `form` elements. You'll need to wrap them inside block elements such as `p`, `dip` or `fieldset`.

This is not the case with **XHTML 1.0 Transitional**, though. Indeed, the DTD indicates that inline elements are allowed inside `form` elements:

```
<!ENTITY % form.content "(#PCDATA | %block; | %inline; | %misc;)*">
```

For reference: [XHTML 1.0 - DTDs](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/dtds.html#dtdentry_xhtml1-strict.dtd_misc)

Answer (score -2):

Yes.

Did you even try this yourself?

Comment: It works, but I was just wondering if it was allowed in HTML.

Comment: @David: The easiest way to find out would have been to try it and then [validate it](http://validator.w3.org/).

Comment: Pretty much every `<form>` example you find on the web will have other things inside of it. It's hard to conceive of a common use case where none of these things will be inside the form, anyway.