# Form input fails to submit when in a div

Tags: forms, google-apps-script

I replicated the Developer's [example code](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication#forms) with success.  When i insert a div into the form it fails.  How can i submit 'form div input' to a server side function?
* i believe divs and spans are allowed inside forms from [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7060523/are-divs-and-spans-allowed-inside-form-elements)
* uncommenting the divs causes the div 'output' not to update.

html:

```
  <form id="myForm">
    <!--><div>-->
        <input name="myEmail" type="text" />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"
          onclick="google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(updateEmail)
                    .processForm(this.parentNode)" />
     <!--></div>-->
  </form>
<div id="output">
</div>

<script>
  function updateEmail(response) {
    var div = document.getElementById("output");
    div.innerHTML = "<p>" + response + "</p>";
  }
</script>
```

code.gs

```
 function doGet() {
var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index').evaluate()
.setTitle('Web App').setSandboxMode(HtmlService
.SandboxMode.NATIVE);
return html;
}

function processForm(formObject) {
  var response = "";
  response = formObject.myEmail;
  return response;
};
```

Edit:
changed:

```
<input type="button" value="Submit"
```

to:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the HTML file to this:

```
<form id="myForm">
  <div>
    <input name="myEmail" type="text" />
    <input type="button" value="Submit"
          onclick="processFormJs(this.parentNode)" />
  </div>
</form>

<div id="output"></div>

<script>
window.processFormJs = function(argDivParent) {
  console.log('argDivParent: ' + argDivParent);

  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(updateEmail)
    .processForm(argDivParent)
};

  function updateEmail(response) {
    var div = document.getElementById("output");
    div.innerHTML = "<p>" + response + "</p>";
  }
</script>
```

And added a `console.log('argDivParent: ' + argDivParent);` statement.  Then in developer tools, show the console.  I get this error:

```
argDivParent: [domado object HTMLDivElement DIV] 
Failed due to illegal value in property: 0
```

`this.ParentNode` is referring to the DIV and not the FORM.  If I take out the DIV, the object returned is:

```
argDivParent: [domado object HTMLFormElement FORM]
```

Not:

```
argDivParent: [domado object HTMLDivElement DIV]
```

A DIV probably doesn't automatically put INPUT values into it's parent object.

This code does work with a DIV:

```
<form id="myForm" onsubmit="processFormJs(this)">

  <div>
    <input name="myEmail" type="text" />
    <input type="button" value="Submit"/>
  </div>

</form>

<div id="output"></div>

<script>
window.processFormJs = function(argDivParent) {
  console.log('argDivParent: ' + argDivParent);

  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(updateEmail)
    .processForm(argDivParent)
};

  function updateEmail(response) {
    var div = document.getElementById("output");
    div.innerHTML = "<p>" + response + "</p>";
  }
</script>
```

For debugging, you can use `Logger.log("your text here");` then view the Logs.

```
function processForm(formObject) {
  Logger.log('processForm ran: ' + formObject);
  var response = "";
  response = formObject.myEmail;
  Logger.log('response: ' + response);
  return response;
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution and method, both are helpful.  I needed a push in the right direction.

Comment: This works until i wrap it in $(document).ready then argDivParent is undefined in the console.  Dang forms.

Comment: Well, to collect values from input fields, you don't need a form.  You can give the input tag an id `<input id='idTheEmail' name="myEmail" type="text" />`  Then retrieve the value with:  `var getTheEmail = document.getElementById('idTheEmail').value;`